# Mother of Thousands plantlets not growing as expected

Tags: houseplants

A few months ago, a friend and I went to a plant show. She bought a mother of thousand, and I bought a purple heart. I noticed after a few weeks some extra growth in my purple heart pot, and it turned out to be two plantlets from her mother of thousands!

I transferred these to their own pot, and let them start to grow. They are under a grow light in a high area, as my apartment doesn't have great north/south facing windows, and I have an overly curious cat who would happily munch on something very toxic to him.

However, they appear to be growing abnormally. I've looked up pictures and videos of mother of thousands growing from plantlets, and they tend to be bushier, expanding out with large leaves to look as a mother of thousands. Mine are just... growing tall?

[image]

Is this normal? Should I try pinching them down, or is the grow light causing this abnormal growth?

Comment: First guess - they are not what you think they are, and came from something other than your friend's plant, which explains why they don't grow like those do.